# User is Null after Login Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

Created a ASP.Net app with Identity Framework. After user authentication successfully, `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` is `null` and  `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is `false`

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                ApplicationUser user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
                UserManager.AddClaim(User.Identity.GetUserId(),new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,"Admin"));
```

I need to add some Roles to authenticated user after authentication.

Comment: we can get user Id after first redirection only

Answer (score 7):

you will get value in `User.Identity.GetUserId()` after first **redirection** occur. as soon as redirection. it will create cookie, then you use either `User.Identity.GetUserId()` or `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`.

Comment: at what place (function/class) I can assign Roles to authenticated user ?

Comment: @Sami: why you are assigning role after login . It should be stored in Db.